# Adding style to the scene of drawer react native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation, react-native-drawer

I'm trying to style  the scene of drawer, like this image:

[image]

but I cant find any method to do that, only to style the Container: `sceneContainerStyle` method.

anyone can help me?

thank

Comment: I'm also finding the solution. have u find it